# Change base URL to another URL

Tags: php

I can't work this out and would love some help please. Currently my web app is on DOMAIN1.com - I want the button to call for DOMAIN2.com rather than the base URL of DOMAIN1.com

```
<div class="right">
  <a target="_blank" class="uk-button" 
  href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseurl."/menu-".$merchant_info[0]->restaurant_slug;?>">
  <i class="fa fa-cutlery"></i> <?php echo t("View")?></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Er... why not just replace `request->baseurl` with `'domain2.com'`?

Comment: I tried that but it didnt like it - let me try again, I may have left a space or not done a '

Comment: Indeed, it does not like that.  That was my original thought too but alas

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't reproduce this issue. The direct replacement of `request->baseurl` in [my Repl.it](https://repl.it/@esqew/VariablePlaintiveComputerscience) works for me.

Comment: So eg href="<?php echo Yii::app()->domain1.com"/menu-".$merchant_info[0]->restaurant_slug;?>">

Comment: That wouldn't be valid PHP syntax, nor would `domain1.com` be a member of the `Yii::app()` object. If that's your edit pending in the queue, I'll post an answer based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided in your edited question and the associated comments, you're attempting to replace a reference to an object property with a string. In your comment, you mentioned you'd attempted with the following HTML/PHP:

```
href="<?php echo Yii::app()->domain1.com"/menu-".$merchant_info[0]->restaurant_slug;?>">
```

What you've attempted to do here is directly replace references to a property of the `Yii::app()` object with a string, however there are two issues here:

1. You've replaced only part of the object reference, which will lead to errors: the way you've re-written the call, PHP will look for a member *within* the `Yii::app()` object called `domain1.com` (which doesn't exist). Initially, I assume the call looked something akin to `Yii::app()->request->baseurl`. Broken down, this is retrieving the value for `baseurl` from the `request` object, which is a property of the object returned by the statement `Yii::app()`. Since we won't be asking the `Yii::app()` object for the `baseurl` anymore, we shouldn't leave that reference there.

   See [PHP: Objects - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) for more information on accessing objects and their properties.
2. You haven't enclosed your `domain1.com` string in double quotes (`"`) to indicate to PHP that it's a string.

   See [PHP: Strings - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) for proper string syntax.
3. You've forgotten a single `.` between the `domain1.com` and `"/menu-"` strings, which will be required to concatenate them.

   See [PHP: Strings - Manual#Useful functions and operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.useful-funcs) for more information on concatenation with the `.` token.

What you're looking for in your PHP call is:

```
<?php echo "domain2.com"."/menu-".$merchant_info[0]->restaurant_slug; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you - I am new to PHP so everyday is a school day. So this got me a step further than before however when I click the link it is opening: DOMAIN1.COM/merchant/DOMAIN2.com/menu-brooklyn-pizza%20%20%3Ci%20class=